# Exclude sub-flow with MUnit

Tags: java, mule, munit

Is there a way for me with MUnit to end the test and add the asserts when the sub-flow is called?
I would like to split the tests up into smaller parts.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to mock the result of the sub-flow.

To do this you have to use the Mock component in MUnit.

What it does is you will have to define an expected output once the sub-flow/flow reference is called.

Here's a quick example:

```
        <mock:when messageProcessor=".*:.*" doc:name="Mock Get Email Recipient">
        <mock:with-attributes>
            <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['getEmailRecipient']"/>
        </mock:with-attributes>
        <mock:then-return payload="hello@gmail.com" mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </mock:when>
```

What this does is it mocks the **getEmailRecipient** flow to return the static value **hello@gmail.com** when it is called in the test.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it works, but maybe you could try to mock the result of the subflow with the mock message processor, like this

```
<mock:when messageProcessor="mule:sub-flow">
   <mock:with-attributes>
      <mock:with-attribute whereValue="<the_name_of_your_subflow>" name="doc:name"/>
   </mock:with-attributes>
</mock:when>
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor)

Hope it helps.

/T

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in code? I have written the MUnit tests using java code instead of xml.

Comment: You have the documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor#defining-mocks-with-java-code)

Answer (score 1):

As the guys said, the way to achieve what you want is with a mock.
Just to be clear you won't be stoping the test you'll be just defining a behaviour to be executed instead of the actual code. Assertions will come later in your test.

Here are a few doc pages that we'll help you with this topic:

- [Mocking](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor)
- [Mocking Sub-flows](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor#a-word-about-mocking-flow-ref) (they are a corner case)
- [Mocks in Java](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/mock-message-processor#defining-mocks-with-java-code)

Finally, even though each MUnit message processor has a Java example at the bottom of each doc page there is an specific page on how to write Java based MUnit Test:

- [Java Based MUnit Tests](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/munit-tests-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.2.0/mock-message-processor#a-word-about-mocking-flow-ref) explains about mocking flow and sub-flow in xml.

To mock sub-flow in Java, you should use `org.mule.modules.interceptor.matchers.Matchers.contains` matcher inside `withValue`.

Arguments to contains should be name of your sub-flow or any regex pattern string.

```
        whenMessageProcessor("sub-flow")
            .withAttributes(
                    Attribute.attribute("name")
                    .withValue(Matchers.contains("my-subflow-name")))
            .thenThrow(new Exception("Test"));
```

Same trick works to mock subflow in `verifyMessageProcessor` too.

HTH!